# How to change the html of a HTMLPanel

Tags: java, html, gwt, panel

I want do declare a Subclass of an HTMLPanel.
In its constructor I want to give it a few paramters to construct the containing html.

Because I have to call the super-constructor as first statement, I have to change the html later in the constructor.

How can I do this?

```
public class MyHTMLPanel extends HTMLPanel
{ 
  public MyHTMLPanel(String id, int anotherParameter)
  { super("");
     String html=""
    // ... some code th construct the html
    //??? this.setHtml(html);  
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to subclass HTMLPanel. You can create a simple Composite widget:

```
public class myPanel extends Composite {

    private HTMLPanel panel = new HTMLPanel();

    public myPanel(String id, int anotherParameter) {
        // set HTML to panel based on your parameters
        initWidget(panel);
    }
}
```

Comment: In what way does this answer the question?

Comment: It does not answer the question.

Comment: It offers a solution to the problem posted in the question. You may prefer a different solution - this is your prerogative, but down-voting it is plain rude. The next answer offers the same approach (extends Composite) and has 3 up-votes.

Comment: I don't think your answer actually answers the question, thus the downvote. It's not rude at all. It's following the rules. You never set the HTML in your answer, and that was the OP's question -- "//??? this.setHtml(html);" and you didn't answer that.

Answer (score 3):

You can find below an example I used and worked well for me.
I don't remember why I don't sub-class HTMLPanel, whether a good reason or not.
You will notice a mechanism to randomize the html ids in case you include several objects of the same type in a single page.

```
public abstract class HtmlPanelBase extends Composite
{
  private String _dynPostfix = "";
  protected final String id(final String staticId) { return staticId + _dynPostfix; }
  private final String wrapId(final String id) { return "id=\"" + id + "\""; }
  private final String wrapDynId(final String refId) { return wrapId(id(refId)); }

  private String _htmlAsText = null;
  public String getHtmlAsText() { return _htmlAsText; }

  abstract protected String htmlPanelBundleHtmlText();
  abstract protected List<String> idList();

  protected HTMLPanel _holder = null;
  private HTMLPanel createHtmlPanel(final boolean defineGloballyUniqueIds)
  {
    // Referent HTML panel text containing the reference id's.
    _htmlAsText = htmlPanelBundleHtmlText();
    if (defineGloballyUniqueIds)
    {
      // List of id's in the HTML Panel reference page to replace with dynamic/unique id's.
      final List<String> refIdList = idList();
      // Replace the reference id's with dynamic/unique id's.
      for (String refId : refIdList)
        _htmlAsText = _htmlAsText.replace(wrapId(refId), wrapDynId(refId));
    }
    // Return the HTMLPanel containing the globally unique id's.
    return new HTMLPanel(_htmlAsText);
  }
  public HtmlPanelBase(final boolean defineGloballyUniqueIds)
  {
    setup(defineGloballyUniqueIds);
    initWidget(_holder);
  }

  private void setup(final boolean defineGloballyUniqueIds)
  {
    if (defineGloballyUniqueIds)
      _dynPostfix = "_" + UUID.uuid().replace("-", "_");
    _holder = createHtmlPanel(defineGloballyUniqueIds);
  }
}
```

And now how you could sub-class from the above base:

```
public class HtmlPanelTemplate extends HtmlPanelBase
{
  private final static boolean _defineGloballyUniqueIds = false;
  private final static int _numIdCapacity = 40;

  public HtmlPanelTemplate()
  {
    super(_defineGloballyUniqueIds);
    setup();
  }

  @Override
  protected String htmlPanelBundleHtmlText()
  {
    return YourClientBundle.INSTANCE.getYourFileHtml().getText();
  }

  @Override
  protected List<String> idList()
  {
    final List<String> idList = new ArrayList<String>(_numIdCapacity);
    return idList;
  }

  private void setup()
  {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
htmlPanel.getElement().setInnerHTML(...)
```

Don't know whether this works in derived class' constructor. But setting up a class for specific content text isn't really a good solution.