# Making a GWT app multipage

Tags: java, gwt

By multipage I mean separate HTML files, say index.html, admin.html etc.

Now one solution to achieve this is to have this in the EntryPoint class:

```
 if (!Window.Location.getPath().toLowerCase().endsWith("myhtmlpage.html") {
   return;
 }
```

The thing I want to understand deeply here is what is my GWT app have the main app, admin app, etc. The tendency of the app nocache.js file will get bigger, thus longer to load.

The question would be, does the code above prevent other parts of the compiled GWT app to load unnecessary parts of the app, say athe code for the Index EntryPoint or the Admin EntryPoint are loaded separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right Patrick,

In addition, there is no way to use the code splitting method for js libraries that are not in your project (not GWT). So splitting pages is right to avoid js libraries you use for your admin code but you don't use in your front office, that's ok if you include the js in the page and you don't inject it through GWT. Otherwise it's your responsibility to split the code (have a common package that is available to all, but individual loads per 'page')

In theory, they say, the good split point is an activity (but I'm not convinced, since I have many activities in my pages, and loading each script alone could be bad for performance, so it's a per case analysis), you can see all what is included in your split in the [compiler report](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCompileReport.html)

Take the time to look this video, it will save you a lot of troubles
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0F5zc1UAt2Y

Answer (score 2):

No, your if/return statement would not prevent any unnecessary javascript code to load.

The standard way to partition the UI javascript code is through [code splitting](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodeSplitting.html).

The standard way to emulate multiple pages is by managing [history & hyperlinks](http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=232).  Basically use tokens to manage your app states with hash code at the end of url -- e.g., #home, #admin.

A pattern I like is a combination of the above two.  For a page that does not need to load initially, I hide it behind a GWT.runAsync code-splitting call to server with a distinct history token.  For pages for which I want to dynamically control the content on the server side without having to recompile the javascript, I create a server call I fully control that returns html displayed on the browser through GWT [HTMLPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12993095/how-to-change-the-html-of-a-htmlpanel/12993329#12993329) -- of course no need to recompile as long as the html structure and corresponding HTMLPanel code do not change.  A side advantage of the latter is that you may control your server side logging to track page load statistics.

Finally, you may want to read up on GWT Activities & Places, from what I read a standard for dealing with history & such.