# Loading HTML templates via Ajax from Google Web Toolkit?

Tags: java, gwt

For my gwt app, I have certain html templates that are stored as static .html files on my website. e.g example.com/views/signup.html , example.com/views/foo.html , etc.

I want this to be a single page app like Twitter, so the user would navigate through all the pages without the page being refreshed.

I will have a HTMlPanel as the root element of my app on the host page. Whenever the user navigates to a different page, e.g by clicking a link in the navigation menu, I want to load the .html template for that page via ajax, and set the returned html into the HTMLPanel.

Is this a plausible solution? If so, how can I load the html templates via ajax from GWT?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to look at this [SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20639998/making-a-gwt-app-multipage/20648107#20648107).

The idea is:

1. You create a server call (e.g., RPC) to fetch your html template as a String.
2. You create a corresponding HTMLPanel that knows how to attach dynamic elements to your html template that you pass in the constructor.
3. You add this newly constructed HTMLPanel to your page root panel where you want it.

[On this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12993095/how-to-change-the-html-of-a-htmlpanel/12993329#12993329) you can find a panel template code that may help you.  The version therein does not have the "dynamic" html source, instead it is hard-coded in a ClientBundle.  But it is easy to extend so the source html is dynamic, simply add a construtor like:

```
public HtmlPanelBase(final String htmlContentAsText)
```

where `htmlContentAsText` is your template html String from your server as follows:

```
public class HtmlPanelBase extends Composite
{
  private String _dynPostfix = "";
  protected final String id(final String staticId) { return staticId + _dynPostfix; }
  private final String wrapId(final String id) { return "id=\"" + id + "\""; }
  private final String wrapDynId(final String refId) { return wrapId(id(refId)); }

  private String _htmlContentAsText = null;
  protected String getHtmlContentAsText() { return _htmlContentAsText; }

  private ArrayList<String> _idList = null;

  protected HTMLPanel _holder = null;
  private HTMLPanel createHtmlPanel(final boolean defineGloballyUniqueIds)
  {
    // HTML panel text containing the reference id's.
    if (defineGloballyUniqueIds)
    {
      // Replace the reference id's with dynamic/unique id's.
      for (String refId : _idList)
        _htmlContentAsText = _htmlContentAsText.replace(wrapId(refId), wrapDynId(refId));
    }
    // Return the HTMLPanel containing the globally unique id's.
    return new HTMLPanel(_htmlContentAsText);
  }

  public HtmlPanelBase(final String htmlContentAsText, final ArrayList<String> idList, final boolean defineGloballyUniqueIds)
  {
    _htmlContentAsText = htmlContentAsText;
    _idList = idList;
    this.setup(defineGloballyUniqueIds);
    super.initWidget(_holder);
  }

  public HtmlPanelBase(final String htmlContentAsText)
  {
    this(htmlContentAsText, null, false);
  }

  private void setup(final boolean defineGloballyUniqueIds)
  {
    if (defineGloballyUniqueIds)
      _dynPostfix = "_" + UUID.uuid().replace("-", "_");
    _holder = createHtmlPanel(defineGloballyUniqueIds);
  }
}
```

To use, fetch your htmlContentAsText on sever (could depend upon locale), upon success instantiate a derived class of the above base template passing the fetched htmlContentAsText in the constructor, and add therein all your logic modifying or adding upon the base html -- e.g., add handlers in response to user actions.

Comment: Can you explain how this code is different from just using a regular HTMLPanel? Also, I don't see a way of changing the html code of this panel, can you clarify?

Comment: @ClickUpvote In essence, it is HTMLPanel.  The only added function of this base class is the optional dynamic ID override needed if you instantiate the same panel/template multiple times in the same page.  I am now thinking inheritance would be a cleaner design, I will try.  The html code can be manipulated through the HTMLPanel holder interface, meant to be done in the derived class.  Most common is to attach GWT objects to html elements with ID's, e.g., adding a button.  Later, I can add some sample code doing so if helpful.

Comment: Off topic, you do know that using underscores in variable names is really ugly. It reminds me of PHP and its hacks.

Comment: @ClickUpvote :), yes I am aware using underscores for member variables is no longer popular, but I don't understand why not.  I find it a useful habit to pay this little visual differentiating respect to those special variables!  The aesthetics suits my eyes!  If you know of good articles making the case of how it actually is useless, I'd read up on it.

Comment: Underscore for private variables is a convention in javascript and in PHP 4, where there's no concept of public/private. But when you declare a variable already private, there's no need to make it look ugly by adding that underscore.

Answer (score 3):

That is precisely the case of http://gwtproject.org site.

It uses [gwtquery](http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/) to load an html page via ajax and insert it in a certain area of the page via the [load()](http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/wiki/Ajax#load%28%29) method.

```
 // Load the file.html using ajax, and append the fragment with id=mid from 
 // the returned document inside the element with id=c in the current document.
 $("#c").load("file.html #mid");
```

You can take a look to the [GWTProjectEntryPoint.java](https://gwt.googlesource.com/gwt-site-webapp/+/master/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/site/webapp/client/GWTProjectEntryPoint.java) (line 128) of the gwt-site-webapp as well.

Of course you have to handle any click on any anchor present in the inserted fragment, to do the appropriate action instead of replacing the gwt application. That can be done with the `live()` method of gQuery.

```
 $("#c").live("click", new Function() {
     public boolean f(Event e) {
        String href = $(e).attr("href");
        // Do something with href.
        return false;
     }
 });
```